# Return a Direction instance by input degrees or empty Optional if there is none

Tags: java, enums

guys. I have an enum class with directions and degree values in them. With "ofDegrees" method, I have to return a Direction object with the name of field (for example: SW) if input degrees match with direction degrees, and if there's no match to return empty Optional.

I tried with converting the degrees input to object and then check for equality between the input and enum values.

```
public enum Direction {
N(0), NE(45), E(90), SE(135), S(180), SW(225), W(270), NW(315);

Direction(final int degrees) {
    this.degrees = degrees;
}

private int degrees;

public static Direction ofDegrees(int degrees) {
    Optional<Integer> opt = Optional.ofNullable(degrees);
    Direction direction = null;
    if(opt.isPresent()) {
        Object obj = Integer.valueOf(degrees);
        for(Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            if(dir == obj) {
                direction = dir;
            }
        }
    }
    return direction;        
}
```

}

In every case i get "null" for result. And the other thing that i cant understand is how can i return empty optional when i cant convert from Optional to Direction?

Thanks in andvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're mixing non optional input argument and optional return, then you're compaing Direction object with optional - they will never be equal, probably you need something like this:

```
public static Optional<Direction> ofDegrees(int degrees) {
    for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
        if (dir.degrees == degrees) {
            return Optional.of(dir);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: Note that calling `Direction.values()` will create a new array object every time it's called. If you call this method frequently, you might want to cache the directions.

Comment: @k314159 That is good advice ***for now***, but the Java team is working hard to make your claim false very soon. There has been a lot of recent discussion and planning about how to create "Frozen Arrays", which should obviate the cost of what you are describing.